# Python: How to use a list comprehension to replace Nones in one list with values from another list?

Tags: python

```
a = [0,   -4, 4,    6, 2, 5, 8]
b = [5, None, 3, None, 3, 2, 0]
c = [5,   -4, 3,    6, 3, 2, 0]
```

I want to take `a` and `b` as inputs and get `c`, ideally using a list comprehension. Obviously I could iterate through this with a loop, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant/pythonic solution.

Comment: What's the logic here? The lowest of the 2 or the one that's not `None`?

Comment: I want to replace the Nones with the values in the other list.

Comment: @Johnny - c is the expected outcome of combining a and b - on pos 2 the excpected outcome is 3 - which is the value in b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work:

```
c = [value if value is not None else a[index] for index, value in enumerate(b)]
```

Comment: If you want it even more simplified: `[value if value else a[index] for index, value in enumerate(b)]` - there's not need to write `is not None`

Comment: @user56700 - Yes there is, try adding `0` to b

Comment: @Sayse if I just add `0` to b, i'll get a `list index out of range`, maybe you could elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @user56700 -  sure, try `print("yes" if 0 else "no")`

Comment: @user56700, both ```0``` and ```None``` have boolean values of ```False```

Comment: @Sayse I see it, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `zip` function:

```py
c = [i if j is None else j for i,j in zip(a,b)]
```